# Equivalent definition of ordinal sum

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to prove that two definitions of the ordinal sum are equivalent.

In the  present question I want to prove that given
$$\tag{1}
\alpha+\beta:=\operatorname{ord}(\{0\}\times \alpha\cup \{1\}\times \beta)
$$
it follows that
$$
\alpha+ \operatorname{S}(\beta)=\operatorname{S}(\alpha+\beta)
\text{, where }\operatorname{S}(A):=A\cup\{A\}.
$$

Here is my start:
\begin{align}
\alpha+ \operatorname{S}(\beta)&=\alpha+ (\beta\cup \{\beta\})\\
&=\operatorname{ord}\big(\left(\{0\}\times \alpha\right)\cup \left(\{1\}\times (\beta\cup \{\beta\})\right)\big)\\
&=\operatorname{ord}\big(\left(\{0\}\times \alpha\right)\cup \left(\{1\}\times \beta\right)\cup \left(\{1\}\times \{\beta\}\right)\big)\\
&=\cdots\tag{*}\\
&=\operatorname{ord}\big(\left(\{0\}\times \alpha\right)\cup \left(\{1\}\times \beta\right)\big)\cup \left\{\operatorname{ord}\big(\left(\{0\}\times \alpha\right)\cup \left(\{1\}\times \beta\right)\big)\right\}\\
&=(\alpha+\beta)\cup\{\alpha+\beta\}=\operatorname{S}(\alpha+\beta)
\end{align}

I proved the result
$$
\operatorname{ord}(A\cup B)=\operatorname{ord} A+\operatorname{ord} B,
$$
but $A,B$ have to be woset and disjoint, additionally $A\cup B$ has to be woset.

> How do I fill the gap? Are there already error?
>   Perhaps there are easier ways (transfinite induction?), but I would like to know if there is some technical trick to fill (*).

**EDIT**

I changed my mind... any hint to any type of proof showing the equivalence of (1) with the following definition (2) is welcomed (incl. ref duplicate / ref. textbook):

1. $\alpha+0=\alpha$
2. $\alpha+ \operatorname{S}(\beta)=\operatorname{S}(\alpha+\beta)$
3. if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal then $\alpha+\beta$ is the limit of the $\alpha+\delta$ for all $\delta<\beta$.

Comment: So you are concerned about how to demonstrate the usual definition of the sum of ordinals in terms of well-ordered sets is equivalent to the recursive definition of the sum. I have a clear and full answer to this question, but I have a lot of work today, so I hope you could be patient, and wait, lets say, 12 hours for me to post the answer. My only hint is that the fact that $\alpha+\beta^+=(\alpha+\beta)^+$ is just one of the three fundamental properties that can define the sum recursively; think about what happens when you are adding a non-succesor ordinal; that case has not been treated yet

Comment: @Akerbeltz: Don't use $\cdot^+$ to denote successor ordinals. Preferably ever.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why not? I think it is good notation, and it is the one I have been using so far

Comment: @Akerbeltz Thank you, this is good news.

Comment: @Akerbeltz: Because it's the ***cardinal successor*** in all standard set theoretic references. (At least those aimed for people who study set theory, I'm ignoring those covering naive set theory for non set theorists.) This would be equivalent to using $\Bbb N$ to denote "the null set".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove the following

> **Theorem**: For each ordinal $\alpha$, the following equalities characterize the operation $\xi\longmapsto\alpha+\xi$:
>
> $$\begin{cases}
>   \alpha+0=\alpha\\
>   \alpha+S(\beta)=S(\alpha+\beta)\\
>   \alpha+\gamma=\text{sup}\{\alpha+\delta\;|\;\delta<\gamma\}\quad\text{if }\gamma\text{ is a limit ordinal}
> \end{cases}$$

But first, let's prove the following:

> **Lemma**: For any ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$:
>
> (a) $\alpha+0=0+\alpha=\alpha$
>
> (b) $\alpha+1=S(\alpha)$
>
> (c) $\alpha+(\beta+\gamma)=(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma$ (associativity)
>
> (d) $\alpha+S(\beta)=S(\alpha+\beta)$

**Demonstration**:

(a) Let $\langle A,<_R\rangle$ be a well ordered set of ordinal $\alpha$. The only well ordered set of ordinal $0$ is the empty set $\varnothing$, so the ordered sum has as base set $A\cup\varnothing=A$ and its well-order is simply the well-order $<_R$ of $A$, so its ordinal is $\alpha$ and $\alpha+0=\alpha$. Similarly, we can obtain $0+\alpha=\alpha$.

(b) Let $\langle A,<_R\rangle$ be a well ordered set of ordinal $\alpha$ and let $\langle\{b\},<_S\rangle$ be a well ordered set of ordinal $1$ such that $b\not\in A$. The ordinal $\alpha+1$ of the ordered sum $\langle A\cup\{b\},<_{R\oplus S}\rangle$ is $S(\alpha)$, because

$$\langle A\cup\{b\},<_{R\oplus S}\rangle\cong\langle S(\alpha),\in_{S(\alpha)}\rangle$$

Via the isomorphism $f:A\cup\{b\}\longrightarrow S(\alpha)$ defined by: for each $a\in A\cup\{b\}$

$$f(a)=\begin{cases}
  g(a)\quad\text{if }a\in A\\
  \alpha\qquad\,\text{if }a=b
\end{cases}$$

Where $g$ is the isomorphism between the well ordered set $\langle A,<_R\rangle$ and $\alpha$.

(c) Let $\langle A,<_R\rangle,\;\langle B,<_S\rangle$ and $\langle C,<_T\rangle$ be well ordered sets of ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ respectively, such that $A,B$ and $C$ are pairwise disjoint. The ordinal $\alpha+(\beta+\gamma)$ is the ordinal of the well ordered set $\langle A\cup(B\cup C),<_{R\oplus(S\oplus T)}\rangle$, and the ordinal $(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma$ is the ordinal of the well ordered set $\langle(A\cup B)\cup C,<_{(R\oplus S)\oplus T}\rangle$. This well ordered set are not only isomorphic but identical, because $A\cup(B\cup C)=(A\cup B)\cup C$ and $<_{R\oplus(S\oplus T)}=<_{(R\oplus S)\oplus T}$, so their respective ordinals are equal, i.e. $\alpha+(\beta+\gamma)=(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma$

(d) $\alpha+S(\beta)=\alpha+(\beta+1)=(\alpha+\beta)+1=S(\alpha+\beta)$

For the last part of the theorem, we just have to prove the following:

> **Lemma**: For any ordinals $\alpha$ and $\gamma$, if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal, then
>
> $$\alpha+\gamma=\text{sup}\{\alpha+\delta\;|\;\delta<\gamma\}$$

**Demonstration**: We must prove the two corresponding inequalities. First, for each $\delta<\gamma$, we have that $\alpha+\delta<\alpha+\gamma$ (cf. Hrbacek & Jech *Introduction to Set Theory*, page 120, lemma 5.4 (a)), so

$$\text{sup}\{\alpha+\delta\;|\;\delta<\gamma\}\leq\alpha+\gamma$$

On the other hand, let $\eta<\alpha+\gamma$. We shall prove that there exists some $\delta<\gamma$ such that $\eta\leq\alpha+\delta$. We have that $\eta<\alpha$ or $\alpha\leq\eta$. In the first case, we simply take $\delta=0$. In the second case, we know there exists some $\beta$ such that $\eta=\alpha+\beta$ (cf. Hrbacek & Jech *Introduction to Set Theory*, page 121, lemma 5.5), and since $\eta<\alpha+\gamma$, it results that $\beta<\gamma$. So taking $\delta=\beta$, we have that $\eta\leq\alpha+\delta$, and

$$\alpha+\gamma\leq\text{sup}\{\alpha+\delta\;|\;\delta<\gamma\}$$

For the other part of the equivalence, that is, supposing that we **define** the sum of ordinals recursively, and we want to prove that the sum of ordinals is the ordinal of the ordered sum of two well ordered disjoint sets, just take a look again at the book of Hrbacek & Jech, page 120, theorem 5.3, where this fact is proved in full detail.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go through the details tomorrow. I had (a) and (c); the proof of (d) is nice. I do not have enough points to upvote your answer.

Comment: Yes, you are just missing two points. Don't worry about it.

Comment: There is a small problem. In the second lemma you accept the result $\delta<\gamma\to\alpha+\delta<\alpha+\gamma$ from Hrbacek, but Hrbacek to prove it uses exactly your second lemma (that in its case is the third condition of the definition he start from: our definition (2)).
A solution could be an alternative proof of $\delta<\gamma\to\alpha+\delta<\alpha+\gamma$ (and I think I have one, I'll check). From which we could derive the continuity of +, that is,
$\alpha+\gamma=\sup\{\alpha+\delta:\delta<\gamma\}$.

Comment: @SethAlire Oh, didn't notice that at all, I usually use this book as a good reference for all these matters. However, in order to prove the strict inequality, you just have to apply the definition of the sum of ordinals. It is a pretty easy thing to prove, but if you are still curious about it, I suggest you to post a question in this site; maybe I can answer it.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I think I got it: $\delta\subsetneq \gamma$ implies  $\{0\}\times \alpha\cup \{1\}\times \delta\subsetneq \{0\}\times \alpha\cup \{1\}\times \gamma$.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't guarantee that the ordinal of the first sum is *strictly less* than the ordinal of the other one.

Comment: Think for example that $\omega=1+\omega$. Why in this case $\omega\not<1+\omega$? The first can be considered as a proper subset of the second, but their ordinals are just the same.

Comment: I insist; if you are having trouble with this question, you should post a question about it

Comment: Ok, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264128

Answer (score 1):

For short let $X=(\{0\}\times \alpha)\cup (\{1\}\times \beta).$

From the 3rd line of your "start" we have $$\alpha + S(\beta)=$$ $$=ord \,(X\cup (\{1\}\times \{\beta\})\,)$$ $$==ord \,(\, (\{0\}\times X)\cup (\{1\}\times \{\beta\})\,)=$$ $$=ord\,(\,(\{0\}\times X)\cup (\{1\}\times \{\alpha+\beta\})\,)=$$ $$=ord\,(\,(\{0\}\times (\alpha+\beta)\,)\cup (\{1\}\times(\{\alpha+\beta\})
\,)=$$ $$=S(\alpha+\beta).$$

Comment: (1) What is reasoning behind the step from the 3rd to the 4th line? Isn't an isomorphism $\beta\cong\alpha+\beta$ necessary? (2) In the 5th line shouldn't be the curly brackets around the first $\alpha+\beta$ normal brackets?

Comment: You are right about the typo in line 5, which I fixed.......$ \{1\}\times \{\beta\}$ is ONE member, and the largest member, of the ordered set displayed in line 3. If we replace $\{1\}\times \{\beta\}$ with any $\{1\}\times \{y\}$ we get an isomorphic  lexicographically ordered set because any other member is of the form $\{0\}\times \{z\}.$..... Don't confuse $\{1\}\times \{\beta\}$  with $\{1\}\times \beta.$

Comment: Now I got it! Thank you. You replaced a singleton with one singleton.