# Ordinal sum inequality - Proof check

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, ordinals

**Definition of addition** Given $\alpha,\beta$ ordinal numbers, then
$$
\alpha+\beta=\operatorname{ord}\big(\{0\}\times\alpha\cup\{1\}\times\beta\big).
$$

**Lemma** Given three ordinals $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, then 
$$
\alpha<\beta \to \gamma+\alpha<\gamma+\beta.
$$

**Proof**
Given $\alpha<\beta$, then 
$$\tag{1}
\alpha\subsetneq\beta, 
$$
$\alpha$ is an proper initial segment of $\beta$, thus 
\begin{gather*}\tag{2}
\{0\}\times \gamma\cup \{1\}\times\alpha \subsetneq
\{0\}\times \gamma\cup \{1\}\times\beta,
\end{gather*}
and the l.h.s. is an initial segment of the r.h.s., thus the claim follows:
$$\tag{3}
\gamma+\alpha
=\operatorname{ord}\left(\{0\}\times \gamma\cup \{1\}\times\alpha\right) <
\operatorname{ord}\left(\{0\}\times \gamma\cup \{1\}\times\beta\right)
=\gamma+\beta.
$$

Comment: For $\beta>0$ (which is clear if $\beta>\alpha$), $\gamma+\beta$ is the least ordinal that is $>\gamma+x$ for all $x<\beta$. This includes $x=\alpha$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I just added the numbering of equations. Your comment refers to $1\to 2$ or to $2\to 3$? I used that a woset can't be isomorph to a proper initial segment of itself. Just as a note: with $<$ I mean $\lneq$.

Comment: I think the entire thing kind of depends on what definition of ordinal addition you use (or if you have proved anything about that before). Usually ordinal addition is defined inductively, so in that case there would still be something to prove here.

Comment: @MarkKamsma I added the definition of addition that I use.

Comment: Then your proof is entirely correct!

Comment: @MarkKamsma, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\langle A,<_R\rangle,\;\langle B,<_S\rangle$ and $\langle C,<_T\rangle$ be three well ordered sets with respective ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ amd $\gamma$ such that the sets $A,B$ and $C$ are pairwise disjoint. Since $\alpha<\beta$, then the well-ordered set $\langle A,<_R\rangle$ is isomorphic to an initial section $\text{sec}(b,B,<_S)$ of $\langle B,<_S\rangle$.

In the ordered sum $\langle C\cup B,<_{T\oplus S}\rangle$, the initial section $\text{sec}(b,C\cup B,<_{T\oplus S})$ determined by the element $b$ of $B$ is equal to the ordered sum $\langle C\cup A,<_{T\oplus R}\rangle$, so the ordinal $\gamma+\alpha$ is strictly less than the ordinal $\gamma+\beta$ of $\langle C\cup B,<_{T\oplus S}\rangle$

Comment: Nice, could you also check my proof, please?

Comment: @Akerbeltz This proof is actually the same as OP's proof. They also use that $\alpha$ is a strict initial segment of $\beta$ (which translates to your statements about $A$ and $B$). In fact, OP actually explicitly notes that this is a *strict* initial segment, this answer does not.